# Is there a way to grep the gnome-terminals history?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, search, grep

Is the terminals output (i.e. not commands) history hiding somewhere that lets me do something like..

```
grep "foo foo \d{5}" ~/.terminal
```

I'm aware I can simply pipe stuff to grep, or save it to a file rather than putting it in the terminal. It's just that sometimes I've had a program output some stuff I'd like to search through but would rather not rerun it just for greps benefit. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output is not stored in any files, no. But you can use the `script` command to record a terminal session. Just run

```
script
```

Then run your commands as usual. When you type `exit`, you will exit the script program. All input and output can then be found in a file named `typescript` in your current directory. You can use `less -R typescript` to read and search through it.

As usual, it's a good idea to read the manual before using a new command. `man script`